# React JS autoComplete ="off " not working ---Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried all solutions suggested by community. But none of them is working in 2021. Tried

```
autoComplete ="off",
autoComplete ="nope"
autoComplete={'' + Math.random()}
```

Does anyone have a new solution? This is the input component I'm using

```
        <input
             autoComplete={'' + Math.random()}                
             key={name}
             value={value}
             onChange={onChange}
             className="input--custom"
             id={name}
             name={name}
             type={type}
       />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
autoComplete="new-password"
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

> If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a
> new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent
> autofilling of password fields, you can use
> autocomplete="new-password".

Answer (score 1):

It is an [open bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587466) in the Chromium project, on which Chrome is based.

Also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete):

> Note: In most modern browsers, setting autocomplete to "off" will not prevent a password manager from asking the user if they would like to save username and password information, or from automatically filling in those values in a site's login form.

Comment: And they don't seem eager at all to change it.