# Disabling autofill in html forms

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, autofill

Hello I am facing an issue regarding autofill form in html. I have already used "autofill=off" in my html tag however I am still facing the problem of autofill suggestions. If you guys have any idea how to handle it using html or javascript please let me know.

Comment: `autocomplete` should be used as `autofill` is a pseudoclass not an attribute. But it may not work anyway. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233154/994006

Comment: I would like to correct here. I said autofill instead of autocomplete.

Comment: If you arrive here because autocmplete is not working as you think it should using `autocomplete="off"` go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is autocomplete='off' not autofill

Answer (score 0):

Try `autocomplete="off"` on your input or same attribute on the whole `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the autocomplete attribute to your input tag like this:-

```
<form>
  <input autocomplete="off">
</form>
```